# Journey Builder: How often is Mobile Push Demographics data refreshed?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobile, mobilepush

I am trying to use the 'Last Message Open' field from Mobile Push Demographics in a Journey.

Can I use this field in a Decision split activity and how often does the data in this field update?

I am looking into 48 hours wait time before proceeding to the Decision split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Last message open' is a standard attribute in `Mobile Push Data > Mobile Push Demographics`.

Let's say if a customer has opened your push message then using [Marketing cloud SDK](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-configuresdk.html) it communicates to SFMC and says when the message has been opened in almost real time.

So, you can use the 'Last Message Open' from Mobile Push Demographics and check with decision split.